# How to run a titanium module using Titanium 3.2.2

Tags: ios, titanium-modules

I am currently using Titanium 3.2.2 and Xcode 5.1.
I am following this documentation to create a module for my xcode project: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide

But this documentation is quite old and run command isn't excutable in this titanium.
Also how can I run titanium module using titanium application and not through command-line.

Comment: Yes I know how to create a module project. I want to create a titanium module so as to integrate my iOS application build in xcode which has to be integrated in another titanium application.

Comment: I want to run the module just as we run a project in xcode

Comment: I have edited my first comment. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, much more up to date:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide

Mostly you have to build the module and then drop the zip that is created into the correct folder, then add the Module in the Titanium tiapp.xml

Answer (score 0):

See here for using legacy command line command

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Legacy_Command-Line_Interface-section-29004835_LegacyCommand-LineInterface-OSX

In short:

```
alias titanium.py="/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/<VERSION>/titanium.py"
alias ios_builder="/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/<VERSION>/iphone/builder.py"
```

or

```
alias titanium.py="$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/<VERSION>/titanium.py"
alias ios_builder="$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/<VERSION>/iphone/builder.py"
```

And please use titanium.py to create module project. Module projects created by titanium CLI cannot be run by titantium.py

I have created a ticket here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4722

I think this may be a bug or incompatibility of titanium.py, but the project structure may be more appropriate than titanium.py (separate android and ios spaces in one module project), so for now, I just use ti to create a project structure, and copy assets, example and documentation to iphone directory and add .gitignore to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Gulp #FTW

"gulpfile.js for Titanium Module Project"

https://github.com/yomybaby/gulpfile-timodule